# Find value of a , b and c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have to find value of $a$, $b$ and $c$ from the given system of equations:

$$\begin{align} a+b+c&=-6;\\ \\
ab+ac+bc&=3;\\ \\
abc&=10.\end{align}$$

I was trying to find factors of 3rd degree polynomial when I encountered this problem.

Comment: Did you make the equation from a cubic equation you wanted to solve? If so, put that one up instead. For factoring a cubic and/or solving there are better ways. I have a feeling I've been there too.

Comment: Was that polynomial equal (or a multiple of) $x^3+6x^2+3x-10$?

Comment: By Vieta's Formulas, $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3+6x^2+3x-10$.

Comment: Slight correction x³-6x²+3x+10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says that if the roots to your cubic are rational they are among $\pm1, \pm2, \pm5, \pm10$.  A little trial and error finds $1,-2,-5$.  Cubics in class always have at least one rational root.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $c=-6-a-b$ we obtain the two quadratic equations
$$
a^2 - ab - 6a - b^2 - 6b - 3=0,\quad
a^2b + ab^2 - 6ab - 10=0.
$$
Now multiply the first equation by $b$ and substract. Then 
$$
0=b^3 - 6b^2 - 3b + 10=(b+5)(b+2)(1-b),
$$
so that
$$
(a, b)=(-5,-2),(-5,1),(-2,-5),(-2,1),(1,-5),(1,-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

You can start for the equation abc=10 (3). So a=10/bc . So substitute this to the other 2 equations and then you have 2 equations with 2 unknowns. the rest i think is easy. Then you can create an equation which has b as unknown and then find c and finally a. Hope this helps :)

Comment: That method works provided you check separately that $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$, and so on.